# how to store information in a database and display it in a listView?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make a to do list app, which will contain a listView, Button(add) in the main layout. when i click add i want it to go to another activity(AddItem) which will contain a editText and a add button. when i click the add button i want to update the list in my database and when i return to my main activity i want the list to be updated.

Here's what i have so far :

MainActivity class :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    c = helper.getAll(); //the helper is an databasehelper class which contains method get all which returns a cursor of all the entries in the database
    adapter = new newAdapter(c);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void clickAdd(View v) { //when i click the add button in the main activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItem.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

protected void ActivityForResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        helper.insert(data.getStringExtra("item")); //insert will insert the string into the database.
    }
}

class newAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

    public newAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(MainActivity.this, c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        newHolder holder = (newHolder) row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(cursor, helper);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        View row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false); //the row is a layout containing only a textView in a linear layout
        newHolder holder = new newHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return (row);
    }

}

static class newHolder {
    private TextView name = null;
    private View row = null;

    newHolder(View row) {
        this.row = row;
        name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title); 
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c, DataHelper helper) {
        name.setText(helper.getName(c));
    }
}
```

}

AddItem class :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "works");
    setContentView(R.layout.add_layout);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTopic);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd);      
}
public void add(View v){
    edit = et.getText().toString(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("item", edit);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}   }
```

what should i change to make it work, Thank you.

Comment: have you make class for sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the project from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) and just observe and make changes accordingly it is very easy and helpful.